# Android XML layout: Error parsing XML: not well-formed (invalid token) - I did close my View tags

Tags: android, xml, compiler-errors, parsexml

I am getting this error on the `Button` view. From the many questions I saw on SO, it seems that this error arises when you don't close your views properly.

I think I have closed all the tags properly but still getting this error. Why is that?

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="${relativePackage}.${activityClass}" >

    <Button 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout:height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/mainActivity_button1"
        android:onClick="startSecondActivity" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Please clean your project, and change target os on xml view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's an additional/typo `:` in an attribute name.

Replace

```
android:layout:height
```

with

```
android:layout_height
```

The error is not only about unclosed tags but XML syntax problems in general. In XML, you can have only one namespace prefix for an attribute, and namespace prefixes are separated from the name with `:`.

Answer (score 2):

```
<Button 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout:height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/mainActivity_button1"
        android:onClick="startSecondActivity" />
```

Replace  : in an attribute name.

```
<Button 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/mainActivity_button1"
    android:onClick="startSecondActivity" />
```

Comment: `android:android:layout_height` hehehe who gave it +1 ?

Comment: @Selvin I gave this another +1. Typos prove that we're human! ;)

Answer (score 1):

Its ofcourse typo on this line :

```
android:layout:height="wrap_content"
```

replace above line with :

```
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```